# Conflicting SharedInstance during method call with different instance (RestKit)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, restkit-0.20, restkit-0.24.x

I am using Restkit framework for RESTFUL web service.

My Resoucemanager i,e TaskManager and TaskDashboardCountManager are conflicting .
When I call method

```
 [[TaskDashboardCountManager sharedManager] loadTaskCount:^(NSDictionary *task) {}];
```

I am getting the exception

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TaskDashboardCountManager loadTask:failure:]:

loadTask is the method of TaskManager but it is getting called using TaskDashboardCountManger . how do i solve this ?

```
 **RKObjectManager.h**
          @interface AKObjectManager : RKObjectManager

            + (instancetype) sharedManager;

            - (void) setupRequestDescriptors;
            - (void) setupResponseDescriptors;

            @end

    **RKObjectManager.m**
    static AKObjectManager *sharedManager = nil;

    @implementation AKObjectManager

    + (instancetype)sharedManager {
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:BASE_DEVELOPMENT_URL];

            sharedManager = [self managerWithBaseURL:url];

            sharedManager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
            /*
             THIS CLASS IS MAIN POINT FOR CUSTOMIZATION:
             - setup HTTP headers that should exist on all HTTP Requests
             - override methods in this class to change default behavior for all HTTP Requests
             - define methods that should be available across all object managers
             */

            [sharedManager setupRequestDescriptors];
            [sharedManager setupResponseDescriptors];

            AppDelegate *delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            [sharedManager.HTTPClient setDefaultHeader:@"Authorization" value: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"token %@", delegate.key]];


        });

        return sharedManager;
    }

    - (void) setupRequestDescriptors {
    }

    - (void) setupResponseDescriptors {
    }


    **TaskManager.m**
    @implementation TaskManager

    + (id)sharedInstance {
        static TaskManager *__sharedInstance=nil;
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            __sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];

            [__sharedInstance setupResponseDescriptors];
        });

        return __sharedInstance;
    }



    - (void) loadTask:(void (^)(NSArray *task))success failure:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure{

        });


    **#import "TaskDashboardCountManager.h"**

        static TaskDashboardCountManager *sharedManager = nil;

        @implementation TaskDashboardCountManager

        + (id)sharedInstance {
            static TaskDashboardCountManager *__sharedInstance=nil;
            static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
            dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
                __sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];

                [__sharedInstance setupResponseDescriptors];
            });

            return __sharedInstance;
        }

        - (void) loadTaskCount:(void (^)(NSDictionary *task))success failure:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure{
        });
```

Comment: What are they subclasses of? RestKit already offers a shared instance so you could be colliding class methods

Comment: @interface TaskManager : AKObjectManager

Comment: http://restkit-tutorials.com/code-organization-in-restkit-based-app/ -- I am coding according to this tutorial . when i call [[TaskDashboardCountManager sharedManager] loadTaskCount:^(NSDictionary *task) {
  }]; this will execute fine , but when i call [[TaskManager sharedManager] load task {}];  Here i am getting exception . sharedManager holds instance of TaskDashboardCountManger.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have mixed up `sharedInstance` and `sharedManager`. There will be 1 `sharedManager` which will be the first one created, then, any other reference to `sharedManager` no matter which class it's from will return the same instance.

At minimum you need to clean this up. It isn't really clear why `AKObjectManager` has a `sharedManager` method, if it's subclassed then it's logical for the superclass to not be instantiable...

You're better off not trying to use singletons so pervasively and instead create the instances explicitly and use dependency injection.

Comment: Ill send you the same demo project will you please help me ? https://www.dropbox.com/s/8nbykv1nfk12u4h/AKGithubClient-master.zip?dl=0

Comment: 1.allows you to keep setup of required HTTP headers in one place (do that once in AKObjectManager)
2.easier to extend. For example if you want custom default behavior for all your HTTP requests, you override methods in AKObjectManager.
more flexible structure